# Menu item shaking when hovering nav_drop_item

Tags: html, jquery, css

When I hover items after selecting an item, the items are shaking, the class 'nav_drop_open' toggling.

How can I fix this?

```js
$('.nav_drop_item').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('nav_drop_open');
});
```

```css
.nav_dropdown {
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: var(--site-white);
  border: 1px solid #e7f1f9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  z-index: 12;
  display: none;
}

.nav_drop_open .nav_dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.nav_dropdown ul li {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_dropdown ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  color: var(--site-text);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nav_dropdown ul li a:hover {
  background: var(--site-blue);
  color: var(--site-white);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav_ul">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav_drop_item nav_drop_open">
      <a href="#">About <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <div class="nav_dropdown">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/home/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/home/howitworks">How Plan work?</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/home/benefits">Benefits</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a working snippet so its easier for us to find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for you to use javascript for this.

add this to you css

```
.nav_drop_item:hover .nav_dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

and remove the javascript and this css line:

```
.nav_drop_open .nav_dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

This wil also fix the flickering